# Box Blur simplified CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I am hoping someone can help me. I am having a really hard time with the box blur problem in pset4. I am trying to simplify the concept so I can actually understand it. I moved away from the bitmap and I am just trying to figure out how to get the average of a box in a 2D array. My current formula will find the average for the whole box.

So I would like to be able to look at arx[0][0] and get the average for the 3 boxes around it plus the [0][0] box.

So it would look like 1 + 1 + 1 + 3
Average would be 1.5 (would show as 1)

then look at the next box
arx[0][1]

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 3 = 10
10/6
2

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

int height = 4;
int width = 4;
int arx[4][4] = {{1 ,1, 1,3}, 
                { 1, 3, 3,1}, 
                { 3,3, 3,3}};

int counter = 0;
int average = 0;

int x[width][height];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < height && j >=0 && j < width)
            {
                sum += arx[i][j];
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
             
            }
        }
    }        
printf("%i TOTAL\n" , sum / counter);
printf("%i", counter);
}
```

Comment: You need 4 loops: one for the width, one for the height, one for the width of the box, and one for the height of the box.

Comment: CS50 is for C code. Why is this tagged C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum all the values at the indexes all around the current one at (x,y):

```
(x-1,y-1)   (x,y-1)   (x+1,y-1)
(x-1,y)     (x,y)     (x+1,y)
(x-1,y+1)   (x,y+1)   (x+1,y+1)
```

Average these 9 values to get the new value of (x,y). Just make sure the indexes are not out of bounds.

```
int main(void)
{
    int height = 4;
    int width = 4;
    int arx[4][4] = {{1 ,1, 1, 3}, 
                     {1, 3, 3, 1}, 
                     {3, 3, 3, 3},
                     {2, 2, 2, 2}};

    int counter = 0;
    int average = 0;

    int x[width][height];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            counter = 0;
            sum = 0;
            // Sum surrounding values
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                    int col_index = col + x;
                    int row_index = row + y;
                    // Ensure legal indexes
                    if (col_index >= 0 && col_index < width && row_index >= 0 && row_index < height) {
                        sum += arx[row_index][col_index];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            x[row][col] = sum / counter;
        }
    }
    // x array now contains the blurred array
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Johnny! This helps immensely.